# Is it ok to post simple puzzles?

Tags: discussion, puzzle-difficulty

I am new here to the site, and I really love it.

The puzzles are entertaining and funny, and I would like to participate, but I noticed some of you are really smart and expert. However for other people (like me) it's a new thing.

The puzzle that I created (a blog with hidden messages and keys) is intended for normal people, not experts.

Is it ok to post a puzzle which is simple yet funny?

E.g. a puzzle intended for low reputation people who are not really expert but they would like to try and get entertained?

In every type of game and entertainment there are levels: easy, medium and hard - so for example the puzzle I would like to post would be easy for high reputation users but for low reputation people, they can solve it if they think a bit.

Comment: Part of this question duplicates the other question but part of it doesn't, so I'm going to do some pretty heavy editing to the question so we can keep the part that's not a duplicate. Roll back my edit if you disagree...

Comment: As the highest-rep user, let me just add that "high reputation user"/"low reputation user" are not at all synonyms for "skilled puzzle solver"/"unskilled puzzle solver", as you're making it sound :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Is it ok to post puzzles which are simple yet funny?*

Yes - simple puzzles are most welcome.

Not all puzzles have to be hard, and hard puzzles are not necessarily 'better' or more enjoyable than easy puzzles.

If you want to explain, in the question itself, that the puzzle you're posting isn't very difficult and so might be particularly suitable for beginners, then that's absolutely fine.

We're also interested in puzzles where the intended audience is children - they don't even have to be hard enough for adults to find them difficult at all.

***If it's a puzzle, it's welcome here, regardless of its difficulty.***

Comment: thank you for answer anyway Ill post my puzzle hope it suits for this site

Comment: No worries @Moudiz, do go ahead and post it.

Answer (score 4):

One thing to add to AE's answer is to ponder why it is simple. If it is simple because everyone has already heard it, then you would want to make sure that it is not a duplicate of or relatively similar to something already posted.